# Есть ли у QPainter в PyQt методы как у библиотеки Turtle?

Tags: python, pyqt, qpainter, turtle, paintevent

Я пишу программу с графическим интерфейсом на *PyQt5*. 
Она должна отрисовывать картинку **`L-системы`**. 
Для этого я использую `QWidget`, на котором собственно и рисую.

Столкнулся с проблемой: я хочу написать код так, чтобы не пришлось создавать массив с координатами точек, а для этого очень подошли бы команды аналогичные `turtle.left()`, `turtle.right()` и `turtle.forward()`, но только для `QPainter`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли такие? 
А если нет, то хотелось бы узнать, как конвертировать канвас черепашки в `QPixmap`, чтобы отображать его на лейбле.

---

Уточнение: программа перед стартом принимает файл с аксиомой и теоремами, которые она получает через диалог с пользователем (`QFileDialog`), который выбирает текстовый файл с информацией о нужном фрактале. 
Прочитав файл, программа создаёт виджет со слайдером, который переключает количество рекурсий и отрисовывает на виджете результат.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QFileDialog, QSlider, QLabel


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fa = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выбрать файл', '')[0]
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200, 50, 600, 630)
        self.setWindowTitle('L-система с QT и черепашкой')
        self.step = 0

        self.sl = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.sl.resize(600, 30)
        self.sl.move(0, 600)
        self.sl.valueChanged.connect(self.sob)

        self.lay = QLabel(self)
        self.lay.resize(600, 600)

    def sob(self):
        self.step = (self.sl.value() + 1) // 20
        f = open(self.fa, mode='rt')
        a = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        inf = []
        for i in range(1, len(a)):
            inf.append(a[i].strip())
        for i in range(2, len(inf)):
            inf[i] = inf[i].split()
        a = inf[1]
        for i in range(self.step):
            s = ''
            for g in range(len(a)):
                for h in range(2, len(inf)):
                    if a[g] == inf[h]:
                        s += inf[h]
            a = s
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if a[i] == 'F':
                # тут должна быть команда, которая рисует отрезак заданной длинны,
                # не принимая при этом координаты начальной точки
                pass
            elif a[i] == '-':
                # тут должна быть команда, которая поворачивает "карандаш" на 
                # заданное количество градусов
                pass
            elif a[i] == '+':
                # тут должна быть команда, которая поворачивает "карандаш" на 
                # заданное количество градусов, но в противоположную стороно от предыдущей
                pass
            elif a[i] == 'X':
                # просто пропуск действия
                pass
            elif a[i] == 'Y':
                # туоже просто пропуск действия
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, а `L-Systems` — математическая красота растений,
то попробуйте пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore, Qt


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        
        self.angle = 25 
        self.transform = QtGui.QTransform()
        self.translate2 =  0
        self.recursions = 10
        self.resize(670, 645)

        self.origin = (self.width()/2, self.height())
        self.pal = QtGui.QPalette()
        self.pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.setPalette(self.pal)

        self.pen_branch = QtGui.QPen()
        self.pen_branch.setColor(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        
        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.slider_angle = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider_angle.setMinimum(-8000)
        self.slider_angle.setMaximum(8000)
        self.slider_angle.setGeometry(0, 30, self.width(), 30)  
        self.slider_angle.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda value, x=0 : self.setAngleValue(value))
        self.setAngleValue(2500)
        self.slider_angle.setValue(2500)

    def setAngleValue(self, value):
        self.angle = value/100
        self.update()
        
### функция branch могла быть реализована так:
#   после первого вызова функции rotate другая ветвь должна использовать удвоенный угол, 
#   чтобы двигаться в противоположном направлении.
#
#   Обратите внимание: предполагая, что угол равен 30°, если вы вызываете rotate(r) 
#   для правой ветви, тогда вам нужно повернуть (-r * 2) для левой; 
#   таким образом угол "сбрасывается" до исходного значения, 
#  а затем поворачивается на противоположную сторону.
#
#    def branch(self, p, x, r, length):
#        p.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -length)
#        if length > 1 :
#            p.translate(0, -length)
#            p.rotate(r)
#            self.branch(p, 10, r, length * 0.66)
#
#            # повернуть на противоположную сторону
#            p.rotate(-r * 2)
#            self.branch(p, 10, -r, length * 0.66)
#            # обратите внимание, что translation и rotation инвертируются
#            p.rotate(r)
#            p.translate(0, length)
###

    # Обычно лучше использовать функции save() https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#save
    # и restore() https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#restore , которые позволяют 
    # использовать несколько уровней состояний рисования: 
    # вы сохраняете состояние, применяете все необходимые изменения 
    # (pen, brush и любые другие преобразования), тогда вы можете восстановить 
    # предыдущее состояние автоматически; 
    # это упрощает разработку и позволяет получить более читаемый и понятный код; 
    # просто помните, что состояния всегда нужно восстанавливать 
    # до исходного сохраненного "уровня".
    # Вот как может выглядеть функция branch лучше:
    
    def branch(self, p, x, r, length):
        p.drawLine(0, 0, 0, -length)    
        if length > 3:
            # сохранить состояние, "первый" уровень (для текущей функции)
            p.save()
            p.translate(0, -length)
            
            # сохранить состояние для правой ветви
            p.save()
            p.rotate(r)
            self.branch(p, 10, r, length * .66)
            # восстановить на предыдущий "первый" уровень
            p.restore()
            
            # сохранить для левой ветви
            p.save()
            p.rotate(-r)
            self.branch(p, 10, -r, length * .66)
            # восстановить снова
            p.restore()
            
            # восстановить предыдущее состояние
            p.restore()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        p.setPen(self.pen_branch)
        p.drawText(20, 20,  'angle: ' + str(self.angle))
        p.drawText(100, 20,  'trans2: ' + str(self.translate2))
        p.translate (self.width()/2, self.height())
        self.branch(p, 10, self.angle, 200)   
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @dark_buckwheat что не так?

Comment: Ваш пример подходит, но я сам так и не смог разобраться, как у вас реализован поворот. Не могли бы вы подробней описать, как работает функция branch() в вашем коде?

Comment: @dark_buckwheat  Я добавил некоторые пояснения в тексте примера, проверьте. 
Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour